# Getting an API set up from GitHub

Tags: iphone, xcode, git, github, soundcloud

I've set up my github account and I'm ready to go. I'm trying to follow [these instructions](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/Setup.md), for setting up an API wrapper for an iPhone project using Soundcloud, but I'm a bit lost:

```
 1. Go to your project directory.
 2. Add the Cocoa API Wrapper as a Git Subproject

    git submodule add git://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper.git SoundCloudAPI

 3. Update the Subprojects (the API Wrapper includes the NXOAuth2Framework as a subproject)

    git submodule update --init --recursive
```

My questions are: Where do I go in my project directory? The same level as the XCode project file? Also, the command in #2 doesn't really work for me. I get the error:

```
 fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These instructions assume that you're using git for your project. And according to the error message, you don't. So, probably, you want at least to `git init` your project, but probably you will want more.

As for where to go in your project — where you want the `SoundCloudAPI` to reside. Which will be created in the current directory.

Comment: Man, this is so confusing! I don't want my project to reside on GitHub. I just want to get the basic Soundcloud API up and running. Is there not a simpler way to do this?

Comment: if you don't want git, you should replace `submodule add` with `clone` in the first command and omit the second altogether.